# QM Question about the Dirac Delta Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I just wrote down the solution for the bound state of the [Dirac delta potential well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential), for $E<0$, and apparently there is only one specific energy for the bound state, and it is negative. I solved for this just assuming $E<0$. What happens if a particle enters with energy $E<0$ but isn't equal to the bound state energy? I don't understand what the solution is telling me, that there is only one bound state, an exact figure. Does that mean we cannot say what the energy of the impinging particle is until we see what it does? I don't understand why you can't have an $E<0$ that doesn't equal the bound state energy, and if you can, what does that do? In the literature they solve for the bound state energy, then solve for the scattering coefficients for the scattering states. I guess they imply $E$ of the particle can be anything, as long as it's greater than zero. Am I wrong to think they are glossing over this too quickly? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: For unbound states, energy spectrum is continuous, so $E$ can be anything as long as it's $\ge0$. And for bound states it is discrete. A particle with $E<0$ must be already bound, otherwise it's outside of the potential well and is essentially free, thus having $E\ge0$.

Comment: The energy of the impinging particle has nothing to do with the Dirac delta potential, or any other one – it's just whatever kinetic energy that particle happens to have.

Comment: So the kinetic energy has nothing to do with whether or not the particle is bound to the potential or it scatters? Physically what does this mean then? If the energy isn't kinetic energy, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your error in thought is assuming a particle can have negative energy in a potential that's $0$.

A particle travelling in the Dirac-function potential will always experience $V(x)=0$, except at $x=0$. Leaving out the spike at the origin for the time being (after all, an impinging particle cannot see it unless it's there), what can the particle's energy be? As always, the total energy is the sum of kinetic and potential energy: $E=T+V$. In this case, then, $E=T$. I think you'll agree that kinetic energy cannot be negative, so $E\geq0$.

The particle *cannot come in* with negative energy, end of story. It's not physically possible.

Comment: Energy is relative. The kinetic energy is not negative. The reference of potential is different making kinetic energy to look negative.

Answer (score -3):

The particle can have any energy below 0. The energy will not be conserved at the dirac potential location and the particle energy at that location is given by the expression dependent on dirac potential alone. For that miniscule amount of time delta t when the particle is inside dirac potential the energy conservation doesn't hold true but delta t times delta E does hold true according to uncertainty principle.